# How can I create input fields based on the user's choice from a popup menu?

Tags: inputfield, dialog-window

I'm trying to create an interface with *Mathematica*. However, I need some instructions concerning the code below. This is about 10% of what I have in mind, but first I need to know how can I create `ns` `InputField`s after `ns` is defined by the user making a choice from the popup menu.

```
ns : number of station
sf : sound frequency
ws : width of window
```

---

```
CreateWindow[
  DialogNotebook[
  {
    TextCell["Number of Stations: "],
    PopupMenu[Dynamic[ns], Range[2, 8]],

    TextCell["Sound Frequency (kHz): "],
    InputField[Dynamic[sf], String, FieldSize -> 7],

    TextCell["Window Size (ms): "],
    InputField[Dynamic[ws], String, FieldSize -> 7],

    TextCell["Calculation Start relative to the Window (ms): "],
    InputField[Dynamic[cs], String, FieldSize -> 7],

    ChoiceButtons[{DialogReturn[{retNS = ns, retSF = sf, retWS = ws, retCS = cs}]}]
  },
  WindowTitle -> "Fluvial Acoustic Tomography Configuration"]];
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is one solution:-

```
CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[{TextCell["Number of Stations: "],
    PopupMenu[Dynamic[ns, (
        ns = #;
        (* set default values *)
        Function[n, (x[n] = 0)] /@ Range[ns];
        col = Column[InputField[Dynamic[x[#]]] & /@ Range[ns]]) &],
     Range[2, 8]], TextCell["Sound Frequency (kHz): "],
    Dynamic[col], TextCell["Window Size (ms): "], 
    InputField[Dynamic[ws], String, FieldSize -> 7], 
    TextCell["Calculation Start relative to the Window (ms): "], 
    InputField[Dynamic[cs], String, FieldSize -> 7],
    ChoiceButtons[{DialogReturn[
       {retNS = ns, retSF = sf, retWS = ws, retCS = cs}]}]}, 
   WindowTitle -> "Fluvial Acoustic Tomography Configuration"],
  WindowSize -> All];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I was just wondering if there is any way to have at least two empty slots as a default mode (min [ns] = 2) and if input ns is larger than 2, more slots are added.

Comment: @K-1 - You could modify the initialisation to: `ns = 2;
col = Column[InputField[Dynamic[x[#]]] & /@ Range[ns]]`

Comment: @ Chris Degnen: I've already tried that, those slots don't appear unless you click on the popup menu regardless of the initial value of "ns"

Comment: @K-1 - I didn't encounter the problem you mention, but I have updated my answer anyway.  It works fine, at least on Mathematica 9.